# Appium iOS autoAcceptAlerts Closing Native App Alert

Tags: java, ios, appium

I am trying to run tests on an physical iPhone using Appium, Cucumber, and TestNG. The app has quite a few permission alerts that I am handling by setting the driver capability `appium:autoAcceptAlerts, true`. However this is also closing some native app alerts.

Specifically there is an alert that asks the user to confirm if they want to change their password. When autoAcceptAlerts is enabled it is selecting the CANCEL option for me when I would like to handle the alert on a test by test bases.

I tried using the driver setting `acceptAlertButtonSelector` but that never worked for me.

**How can I get Appium to filter out certain alerts for autoAcceptAlerts or temporarily disable it as part of my test step?**

Note: There are some alerts with the same options that appium ignores for the autoAcceptAlert but others it handles itself.

Answer (score 1):

call this method where needed with the required parameter

```java
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
/**
 * Handle alert .
 *
 * @param If true, accept the alert; if false, dismiss the alert.
 */
public void handleAlert(boolean accept) {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        if (accept) {
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any exception that might occur while handling the alert.
    }
}
```